# Visual Studio 2017 app with apache cordova get NetworkError on AJAX Post with Debug-Windowsx64-Local Machine but works with Android and IOS

Tags: visual-studio-2017, apache-cordova, jquery-mobile-ajax

I have this problem with an Apache Cordova Proyect... the debug works perfect with Android Emulator an IOS.... but with windows I get a NetworkError in function (resulta).... this is my code:

```
function Vendedores() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://' + document.getElementById("servidor").value + '/Proformas.aspx/CargaVendedores',
        data: '{pnumero:"0"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        async: false,
        success: function (resulta) {
            $.each(resulta, function (i, field) {
                //some stuff....
            });
        },
        error: function (resulta) {
            alert("no se pudo cargar los vendedores, revisar  conectividad con el servidor");
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Please capture the value of resulta and include it with your question in order to help the community understand the error you are running into.

Comment: O... Error says:   readyState 0 Number
  status 0 Number
  statusText "NetworkError" String